# How to install ADAM on Vista

Tags: windows-vista

I have followed this tut
http://dunnry.com/blog/InstallingADAMOnVista.aspx

but when running adam install it says it cannot install on this OS.

Any solution ?

I have Vista SP1 and people got some error
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistasp/thread/10b77ba6-568b-4b7f-8885-c7f4f49f0d39

but they could have run adam install whereas I can't even do so,

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this thread sheds some light; perhaps SP1 is the reason the tutorial you tried no longer works:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistasp/thread/10b77ba6-568b-4b7f-8885-c7f4f49f0d39

Comment: Until you find a solution, perhaps install it in a virtual machine on Windows XP or another supported OS?

Comment: @BasicallyMoney thanks yes i have checked I have indeed Vista SP1 but it's not the same error message as in the link you gave.

It works of course with VPC but it's not as practical environment and since some people did manage to  install on Vista why not me :)

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8e9b293-c178-4aa7-a9f6-4f386738ca7d/adam-install-on-windows-vista?forum=architecturegeneral)

> Microsoft tells me they haven't decided to support ADAM (now called AD/LDS) on Vista.  They say use XP (really) or Windows 2003 R2 or Windows 2008

Note:

Try here also

*****[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20091201113014/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/cicorias/archive/2007/10/10/Installing-ADAM-on-Vista.aspx)*****

Comment: Hi thanks, it should have worked except I cannot even launch adaminstall